# python/serial broken in OSX lion / launchd

Tags: python, macos, osx-lion, launchd, pyserial

I have a `launchd` entry that worked with OSX 10.6 but that fails with 10.7.  It uses python, and it produces an error whilst trying to import `serial`.  I don't quite understand this, because I've re-downloaded `pyserial-2.5` and re-installed it with sudo.  (In desperation, I re-installed it for each of the many flavours of python on my machine.)  As a test, I can enter python and do `import serial` without difficulties.  Maybe there is a system path that is set up well for an interactive user, that is not set up for launched??

Can anyone suggest how I might diagnose the problem?

Comment: How have you installed pyserial? Via pip?

Comment: Yes, but not using pip.  (I downloaded it and did ``sudo python build`` and then ``sudo python install`` from inside the source file.)  ``pip`` gives as below, which seems to suggest it's OK.  ``$ pip search pyserial
pyserial                  - Python Serial Port Extension
  INSTALLED: 2.5 (latest)``

Comment: Also, I just did ``sudo pip install pyserial --upgrade`` and it still fails.

Answer (score 1):

The path you are appending:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

is the `site-packages` directory for a third-party, non-system Python, possibly installed using a python.org installer, and not that of the Apple-supplied system Python 2.7, which would be:

`/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`

So most likely you are using the python.org Python to install `pyserial` but are launching the system Python under `launchd`.  Check your shell `PATH` (`echo $PATH`), it probably has:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin`

in it. And try `which python`.  If you want to use the python.org Python with your `launchd` plist, modify it to use an absolute path to the right Python, for instance:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`

If you want to install `pyserial` with the system supplied Python, you can use an absolute path to it when doing the install:

`/usr/bin/python2.7`

Answer (score 0):

Some experimentation with `python -S` showed me that the `sys.path` was not set up properly, so I solved the issue by

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
import serial
```

which I *know* is awkward, since it is so specific, but I guess I'll have to live with that, unless or until I can find a way to tell python where to find things, as it is being invoked from `launched`.

PS to anyone coming here later: the switch to OSX 10.7 (Lion) changed loads of things.  Perhaps I had some initialization file somewhere, that I forgot about.  If I find that, I'll try it that way, and post a further comment here.